# Requiring modules gives module not loaded error

Tags: requirejs, reactjs

I am trying to write a simple Hello world app in react.js using component based approach. So I am using requie.js. I have 4 files in the same folder namely `index.html, index.js,world.js and require.js`. I am having a script tag in index.html which will load index.js. But I am loading the world.js via require.js using module.exports, which would result in error. Here is my code

`index.html`

```
<head>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
<!-- In-browser JSX transformer, remove when pre-compiling JSX. -->
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script data-main="index.js" src="require.js"></script>

</script>


</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/jsx" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js

```
var world = require('./world');

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (<div>
        <div>Hello,</div>
        <world/>
      </div>)

  }

})

var element = React.createElement(Hello);

React.render(element,document.body);
```

world.js

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div>World!</div)
  }

})
```

I am intending to show `Hello, World`. But I'm getting the following errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/t39.3284-6/11057100_835863049837306_1087123501_n.js:314 You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx
require.js:8 Uncaught Error: Module name "world" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
:8000/index.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can share the actual code on github and provide a link where it can be downloaded? I think it would be better to have the entire code so that I can see what it's currently doing.

Comment: Yes, it is very much possible. Please give me sometime to push the code

Comment: https://github.com/vamsipavanmahesh/helloworld/tree/master @HatemJaber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three issues here. First, you are not using the correct require syntax for asynchronous loading. Your index.js should be:

```
define(['world'], function(world) {

    var Hello = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return (<div>
                    <div>Hello,</div>
                    <world/>
                    </div>)

        }

    })

    var element = React.createElement(Hello);

    React.render(element,document.body);
});
```

Second, since index.js and world.js are jsx files, requirejs needs a plugin that will tell it that. Something like:

https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin

Finally, since you are loading index.js via requirejs, you don't need:

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the component "world" should start with an upper case. I went ahead and put the code in a single file so that you can see it a little more clear:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <!-- In-browser JSX transformer, remove when pre-compiling JSX. -->
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
    var World = React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        return (
        <div>World!</div>
        );
      }

    });

    var Hello = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
        return (
        <div>
            <div>Hello,
            <World />
            </div>
        </div>
        );

      }

    });

    React.render(<Hello />,document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I would recommend is that you setup a proper environment for development with node and npm installed. I have a project in github that is a skeleton that you can use to get up and running without having to worry about how it works for now: [reactjs skeleton](https://github.com/hatemjaber/reactjs-skeleton).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was to able to code in a style that you did. But wanted to componentize things. So the question was my effort. Thanks for the help nevertheless.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you write components, make sure that component does only one thing, this way things become easier to manage. You should look at setting up an environment, it will make things much easier for development.